# Should 'Other' be a text field or a radio button plus text field

Tags: input-fields, radio-buttons, webforms

[image: Radio buttons plus option input field]
Hi! There's a discussion around whether 'Other' should be a radio button at the end of these options, where an input field then allows you to type in the company formation type.

The first few radio buttons are the common ones, so they're given as options.
We are trying to make this part of the form really easy and quick to go through.

What are your thoughts on best practice with 'Other' input fields?

Thanks

We have also tried it as a dropdown menu, but for the short labels of input it felt over the top.

What to do next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would opt for a radio button with a hidden text field revealed when the button is clicked:

[image]

[Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/dsgdesign/pen/BaNYXVv)

Comment: Why is that? (I agree with the answer.  I think an explanation of your thought process will make it more helpful.)

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Im not the commenter, but my thought process would be that, if there is no "other" option, then users can run into a scenario where they select "Limited/LTD" and type in an "other" option. These two options should be exclusive (i assume), so you can only select one option, either "Limited/LTD" or "other". Hiding or greying out the "other" character box that activates when you select "other" also lets the user know of the dependency between the "other" and the text box. Otherwise, users may not know that the text box and "other" are related.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a radio button for the other option, cause it has to be selected in order to type in the other option. The text field can be either hidden, or be in a disabled state until the other option is selected. I would opt for placeholder text that helps to define what is expected in the other field.